# PHP mySQL Prepared Statements Error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488035/call-to-a-member-function-bind-param-on-a-non-object)

I'm getting the following error:

```
Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object
```

Here's the prepared statement:

```
include('/path/to/connection/variable.php');
```

This file is verified to be working it's just creates an instance of the mysqli class, example:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "db");
```

So I know that's not the issue...

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $firstname, $lastname, $email, $subscribed, $signup_date, $unsubscribe_date, $signup_source);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

Variable types are as follows:

```
$firstname = string
$lastname = string
$email = string
$subscribed = char (Y or N)
$signup_date = DATE - date('Y-m-d')
$unsubscribe_date = DATE - 0000-00-00 Entered Initially
$signup_source = string
```

I've tried to find all the usual suspects, checked the connection, basically I wrote a separate SELECT statement and it works.  "USERS" is a valid table.  Permissions for the connection are root, so that's not the issue.  I've switched the types for dates between "s" and "d", and even tried everything with dummy variables - no difference.

I'm hoping it's something simple - because I've been racking my brain for the past hour now, and I can't see anything wrong with the statement above.

Comment: Yea - I'm receiving `FALSE` on `var_dump($stmt)`, which is what's confusing me, because the statement has the correct syntax, it's a correct table, and the field count is correct, etc.

Comment: Edit: I found the issue - I was missing a field on the INSERT - damn I hate when it's something so simple....  On a related since I'm not the best with mySQL is there a way I can target INSERT for only a couple fields - i.e. exclude trailing fields in the statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That usually means your `->prepare()` call has failed, and returned a boolean FALSE instead of statement object. Check for that:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)") or die($mysqli::error);
```

Comment: It is - I did a `var_dump($stmt)` and it is returning `FALSE`, so I'm at a loss because the statement appears correct.

Comment: Check $mysqli::error for the reason why.

Comment: I found the issue - I was missing a field on the INSERT - damn I hate when it's something so simple....

Answer (score 1):

In response to your question you can do the following:

```
 INSERT INTO tableName (column1, column2, column3,...) 
 VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

Comment: There looks to be 7 to me, the first "variable" holds the field types.

Comment: Ah..thank you sir - I knew there was a way!