# Select query returning error

Tags: php, mysql

I have a basic form where I am able to insert values into mysql db. I am having problems displaying the values previously inserted from the form. There are three tables in mysql db that share `academy_id` as a key. I am getting a php error for my `SELECT` query. What is the best way to properly display values from several table sharing a foreing key? [SITE](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/test/test9.php)

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {


$db_insert  = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO academy (name, type, status, academy_id, street_address, zipcode, city, state, comments) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"); 
$db_insert->bind_param('sssisssss', $_POST['name'], $_POST['type'], $_POST['status'], $_POST['acad_id'], $_POST['street'], $_POST['zipcode'], $_POST['city'], $_POST['state'], $_POST['acad_comm']);
$db_insert->execute();

$academy_id = $_POST['acad_id'];



 //Query to Read Values from database based on academy_id 
$db_select  = $db_con->prepare("
SELECT a.name AS 'Academy Name:', 
       a.academy_id AS 'Academy ID:',
       a.status AS 'STATUS:',
       a.type AS 'Type:',
       a.street_address AS 'Street:',
       a.city AS 'City:',
       a.state AS 'State:',
       a.zipcode AS 'Zip Code:',
       a.comments AS 'Comments:',
       c.course_name AS 'Courses Name:',
       ac.start_date AS 'Course Start Date:',
FROM academy a
WHERE academy_id = $academy_id
INNER JOIN courses_by_academy ac ON a.id = ac.academy_id
INNER JOIN courses_selection_list c ON c.id = ac.course_id
");
$db_select->bind_param("i", $academy_id);
$db_select->execute();
}

?>
<form action="test9.php" method="POST">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"></br> 
        Academy Status:
        <select>
          <option value="ACTIVE">ACTIVE</option>
          <option value="INACTIVE">INACTIVE</option>
        </select>
        Type:
        <select>
          <option value="Upper-Secondary">Upper-Secondary</option>
          <option value="Post-Secondary">POST SECONDARY</option>
        </select>

        Courses being offered?
        <select name="courses_offered">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
        <div id="course_catalog"></div>
        Academy ID: <input type="text" id="acad_id" name="acad_id"></br>
        Address: <input type="text" id="street" name="street"></br>
        Zip Code: <input type="text" id="zip_input" name="zipcode"></br>
        City: <input type="text" id="city" name="city" value=""></br>
        State: <input type="text" id="state" name="state" value=""></br>
        Overall Notes/Comments:</br><textarea id="acad_comm" name="acad_comm" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea></br>

    <input value="SAVE" name="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Remove the extra comma just before the `FROM` and move the `WHERE` to the end.

Comment: Follow @DevlshOne advice and check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488035/call-to-a-member-function-bind-param-on-a-non-object

Comment: For reference, here's the error I see: `Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /home/vhosts/webprolearner.ueuo.com/test/test9.php on line 85`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to structure your joins before the WHERE clause.
It also seems you may be getting an ambiguous field error, as you mention "academy_id" in your WHERE clause, yet you don't specify which table you're checking. I believe you'll get a MySQL engine error when you try it this way.

```
//Query to Read Values from database based on academy_id 
$db_select  = $db_con->prepare("
SELECT a.name AS 'Academy Name:', 
       a.academy_id AS 'Academy ID:',
       a.status AS 'STATUS:',
       a.type AS 'Type:',
       a.street_address AS 'Street:',
       a.city AS 'City:',
       a.state AS 'State:',
       a.zipcode AS 'Zip Code:',
       a.comments AS 'Comments:',
       c.course_name AS 'Courses Name:',
       ac.start_date AS 'Course Start Date:'
FROM academy a
INNER JOIN courses_by_academy ac ON a.id = ac.academy_id
INNER JOIN courses_selection_list c ON c.id = ac.course_id
WHERE a.academy_id = $academy_id
");
```

Also, the error isn't posted here, so it's hard to guess what your problem is.

Comment: Maybe but also this error `ac.start_date AS 'Course Start Date:', FROM` that @DevIshOne already pointed out. That comma before `FROM` shouldn't be there.

Comment: Yep, that's also likely to be a problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well I closed your site when that suspicious as hell media player update box came up... so I can't say for sure, but I can see that you aren't doing anything with the results you are getting back from the DB. The PHP error you mention must be something different.

You need something like

```
foreach ($db_select->fetchAll() as $row)
  {
      echo $row['name'].", ".$row['academy_id']; //do whatever with code
  }
```

Also, you should always put your SQL statements in a try catch block,

```
 try{
$db_select  = $db_con->prepare("
...

}catch(PDOException $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```