# Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in web service

Tags: php

Anyone can help me why this part error ?

Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

```
 // insert query

$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO reports( id, name, category, sub_category, description, status_report, user_design, user_create, time_create, user_update, time_update, attr1, attr2, 'status') values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 1)");

$stmt->bind_param("sssssssssssss", $object, $name, $category, $subCat, $desc, $reportStatus, $userDesign, $userCreate, $timeCreate, $userUpdate, $timeUpdate, $attr1, $attr2);

$result = $stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call to a member function bind\_param() on a non-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488035/call-to-a-member-function-bind-param-on-a-non-object)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Quotes around `'status'` in the list of columns will in your query cause problems

Comment: i'm already delete quotes around status but still same ... @MarkBaker