# Getting Error while using PHP Prepared Statement for Insert "Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object"

Tags: php

I'm using php prepared statement to insert into mysql database, but I'm getting:

> Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

while trying to insert, I tried in Google and everywhere else, but I am still stuck!

```
$loc=$_POST['location'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$chname=$_POST['chname'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$plan=$_POST['plan'];

$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO clinic_registration (location, clinic_name, chief_doctor,clinic_address,clinic_phone,clinic_email,clinic_plan,clinic_username,clinic_password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

$stmt->bind_param("ssssisiss",$loc,$name,$chname,$address,$phone,$email,$plan,$name,$name);

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Probably because your connection is not working (`$con`). Hard to tell from this.

Comment: What are you using? MySQLi?

Comment: `$con` probably contains nothing. You forgot to initialize the PDO. I guess. Hard to tell.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call to a member function bind\_param() on a non-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488035/call-to-a-member-function-bind-param-on-a-non-object)

Comment: ya i saw it but it didnt helped me

Comment: @YUNOWORK $con is fine

Comment: Well it can't be too fine if it doesn't recognize it as an object...try `var_dump($con);` See if it's boolean or something else.

Comment: Oh yeah, `mysqli`, the `$stmt` might be boolean. One of the two

Comment: @YUNOWORK Rasclatt Thanks very much, It Worked for me!!

Comment: after successful execution of query i'M trying to redirect using head{location:login.php} but i'm getting headers already sent errors how to overcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**check the connection**

```
<?php
$con= new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

Comment: @Sagar happy to help :)