# Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in? so what i will do?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$employee_stmt=$con->prepare("INSET INTO employee (emp_name, emp_desig, emp_salary, years_exp, emp_status, emp_adr, city, pin_code, emp_phone, emp_email, emergency_contact, emergency_phone, blood_group, known_health_issue)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

$employee_stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssssss',$_POST['employee_name'],$_POST['designation'],$_POST['salary'],$_POST['exp'],$_POST['emp_status'],$_POST['address'],$_POST['city'],$_POST['pin'],$_POST['phone'],$_POST['emp_email'],$_POST['emr_contact'],$_POST['emr_phone'],$_POST['blood_group'],$_POST['health_issue']);
```

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to encourage people to answer your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4488100/4248328

Comment: I have found sometimes one get errors if you pass in a string instead of a variable storing the string, have you tried that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your statement can not be prepared. You should check SQL for errors. (For example in post `INSET` used instead of `INSERT`).